# Как реализовать прогнозирование?

Tags: matlab

Здравствуйте, у меня есть таблица с факультетами от 1 до 8 и года 2011 2012 2013 c данными.

```
Наименование           2011       2012       2013
показателей
     1                 517,6      292,3      202,1
     2                 16833,6    14703      12482,4     
     3                 386,3      204,5      114,6
     4                 684,1      503,2      393,4
     5                 8839,4     7007,6     6399,3
     6                 31         24         19
     7                 6          5          4
     8                 490,4      534,5      507,8
```

Я бы хотел сделать прогноз на 2014 2015 2016 год с каждого факультета, но когда я пытаюсь сделать прогноз на 2014-2016 с второго факультета с данными от 2011 до 2013 то у меня выходят одинаковые данные. Может я что-то не правильно сделал. Вот моя программка:

```
P = [1 2 3];
T = [16833.6 14703 12482.4];
net = newff([1 3],[25 1],{'tansig' 'purelin'},'trainlm');
net.trainParam.epochs = 300;
net = train(net,P,T);
Y = sim(net,P)
plot(P,T,P,Y,'o')
Q = [ 4 5 6];
Z = sim (net, Q);

P - это 2011-2013 год
T - это данные с второго факультета 
Q - это 2014-2016 год

Вот, что Z дает мне на выходе:
Z =

    12482        12482        12482
```

Где у меня ошибка, так как получаю одинаковые данные? Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться, использую Матлаб R2013b

Answer (score 1):

В вашей программе все время одинаковое значение потому что ваша сеть обучалась на одном диапазоне данных (1 2 3, ваша P), а вы ей подсовываете данные из другого (4, 5, 6). С учетом того что вы используете передаточную функцию с насыщением (tansig) сеть при работе будет реагировать на все числа выше трех как на 3, а на все числа ниже 1 как на 1. При это я почти уверен что реально вам еще и не хватает размера обучающей выборки

Кстати, вы уверены что правильно делаете задание? Когда говорят о прогнозе то очень часто подразумевается закон вида X_t = F(X_(t-1)) , у вас же реализован закон X_t = F(t)

Comment: Я начинающий в этом, мне нужно чтобы был прогноз на 2014 по 2016. Я думал, что Q (4 5 6) должен записывать будущие прогнозы 2014 - 2016.

Эта программка отлично работала на основе 12 месяце. она могла делать прогноз аж на следующие 12 месяцев. 

P = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12];
T = [98 103 113 117 124 115 121 123 128 121 130 137];
net = newff([1 12],[25 1],{'tansig' 'purelin'},'trainlm');
net.trainParam.epochs = 300;
net = train(net,P,T);
Y = sim(net,P)
plot(P,T,P,Y,'o')


Q = [13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24]
Z = sim (net, Q)

вот этот пример работает на 12 месяцев.

Comment: теперь она не работает с моими данными. я не могу понять где моя ошбка

Comment: маленькая обучающая выборка, я же написал + не исключаю переобучения. С 12 выборка была побольше и tansig не отрезал верх (думаю, просто повезло), а тут фокус не прокатил